# Выборка из списка словарей по условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

Есть список словарей:

```
students = [{'name': 'Alex', 'val': 8, 'subj': 'Subj2'},
            {'name': 'Natallia', 'val': 10, 'subj': 'Subj2'},
            {'name': 'Nikodim', 'val': 10, 'subj': 'Subj2'}]
```

Задача:
    Найти в этом списке максимальное значение 'val' с привязкой к 'name' при условии что объекты могут иметь одинаковые значения 'val' - в этом случае отдаем все объекты с одинаковым значением.

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала находим максимальный `val`

```
In [203]: from operator import itemgetter

In [204]: max_val = max(students, key=itemgetter('val'))['val']
```

потом выбираем все элементы с максимальным `val`

```
In [205]: [x for x in students if x['val'] == max_val]
Out[205]:
[{'name': 'Natallia', 'subj': 'Subj2', 'val': 10},
 {'name': 'Nikodim', 'subj': 'Subj2', 'val': 10}]
```

---

Решение при помощи модуля [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html) - скорее всего будет работать гораздо быстрее для больших объемов данных:

```
In [254]: import pandas as pd

In [255]: df = pd.DataFrame(students)

In [256]: df
Out[256]:
       name   subj  val
0      Alex  Subj2    8
1  Natallia  Subj2   10
2   Nikodim  Subj2   10

In [257]: df.nlargest(1, columns='val')
Out[257]:
       name   subj  val
1  Natallia  Subj2   10
2   Nikodim  Subj2   10

In [258]: df.nlargest(1, columns='val').to_dict('r')
Out[258]:
[{'name': 'Natallia', 'subj': 'Subj2', 'val': 10},
 {'name': 'Nikodim', 'subj': 'Subj2', 'val': 10}]
```

Comment: Круто!
Не тривиальное решение, но очень элегантное.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, спасибо, но круто было бы сделать все за один проход по списку - у меня пока не получается...

Comment: @MaxU, я как раз загрузился как это сделать в один проход, но решение приходило только так как вы в принципе и написали. За решение через Pandas отдельное спасибо, взял на вооружение по большим данным. Так, на всякий: если кто задумался над .to_dict('r') - вот описание: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html